# Please help me to get archetype language support in vscode working

Tags: smart-contracts

I am unable to get archetype language support working on vscode

I recieve the following error under the problems tab:

```
Error (parsing)
  Error while analyzing archetype or archetype or archetype 
or archetype or archetype.
```

I am using the JS version of the compiler.

I have tried using the binary version instead and changing the Archetype setting accordingly as per this page: https://archetype-lang.org/docs/installation

I believe I have followed the installation instructions. Completium-cli, opam and archetype all seem to be installed.

After switching to gitpod to continue the tutorial I found there was a similair error so I thought it must be a problem with the extension:

```
    Error (parsing)
      Error while analyzing a variable declaration or a variable
declaration or a variable declaration or ... etc
```

However, I tried reverting to an older version of the extension, and I still have the problem.

Any thoughts on what I can try next?

Thanks,

Grum

[image: vscode Archetype settings]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are some feedbacks based on the screenshots:

1.

- VSCode does not fail to issue an error on `variableS[%...%] ...` since it is not a correct syntax
- the error message is a bit weird, that's the joy of parsing and I get the same one.

Hence I don't see anything wrong based on that.

2.
It seems you want to replicate the miles with expiration verification exercise presented in a Medium article. Unfortunately the article is very dated and many things have changed since then:

- let's start with the bad news: the whyml generation is currently not maintained and most certainly will fail. We stil hope to put it back to business one day. We are welcoming any help on that side.
- the archetype syntax is now stabilised; an up-to-date version of miles with expiration may found [here](https://github.com/completium/archetype-lang/blob/master/contracts/miles_with_expiration.arl), but the whyml generation will fail

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not sure how I got so stuck on this. For any future readers - the most up to date tutorial seems to be here: https://completium.com/docs/contract/tuto/archetype-tutorial